# How do I transfer Integers from python into another programm

Tags: python, export, transfer

I have created a programm that generates prime numbers in ascending order and calculates the difference between a prime number and the following one. It all works but I want to export the differences into another website which creates a graph based of input. Is there any non complicated way to do this. I am a beginner

I haven't really tried anything because I have no idea how to even begin this.

Comment: save them to excel/csv & process from there

Comment: There are many common file formats that can easily be read and written on most computers: CSV, JSON, XML.

Comment: @Bhargav How would I do that. And how would I use that to automate the input into another website